# Difference between let arrayName = [...this.A, this.B] and let arrayName = [...this.A] arrayName.push(this.B)

Tags: javascript

So ive been watching freeCodeCamp's Vue Youtube Tutorial.

At one point they use this code:

```
let answers = [...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers];
answers.push(this.currentQuestion.correct_answer);
```

And then this one:

```
let answers = [...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers, this.currentQuestion.correct_answer]
```

Are they any different? Im more familiar with the push method, but if the other method works and doesnt have any downsides, why bother pushing?

Comment: The result is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are basically equivalent, they both unpack a JS iterator into an array and append to this array a new value. The first method does it by mutating the array, the second at construction.

Answer (score 1):

They are not different.

```
let answers = [...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers, this.currentQuestion.correct_answer]
```

In above case you are just initialising the array with all values.

```
let answers = [...this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers];
answers.push(this.currentQuestion.correct_answer);
```

In above case you are initialising with all the contents of `this.currentQuestion.incorrect_answers`. After that you are pushing `this.currentQuestion.correct_answer`.